# How can I proxy to a ssl endpoint with the webpack-dev-server proxy

Tags: javascript, ssl, proxy, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I try to proxy this `http://localhost:9000/rpc` request, I receive:

```
cannot proxy to https://example.appspot.com:80 
  (write EPROTO  101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:
  SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:794:)
```

webpack-dev-derver config:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: "./",
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 9000,
    proxy: {
        '/rpc': {
            target: 'https://example.appspot.com',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true     // **Update-2 SOLVED**
        }
    }
}
```

I use [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) : `fetch('/rpc' ...` to make the request and Windows 10 professional to run webpack.

Without the proxy : `fetch('https://example.com/rpc' ...` the SSL request works fine.

**Update. I had to use the SSL port 443** (see the answer of Steffen).
Now using: https://example.appspot.com:443

But still not working with `secure: true`. The console log shows:

```
cannot proxy to https://example.appspot.com:443 
(Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: localhost. 
is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.appspot.com, DNS:*.thinkwithgoogle.com,
DNS:*.withgoogle.com, DNS:*.withyoutube.com, DNS:appspot.com,
DNS:thinkwithgoogle.com, DNS:withgoogle.com, DNS:withyoutube.com")
```

And with `secure: false`. The console reports: `404 (Not Found)`

**Update: SOLVED** using `changeOrigin: true`. Docs [here](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#options).

Comment: Thanks for the `changeOrigin: true` solution!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
>         target: 'https://example.com:80',
> ```

It is very unlikely that port 80 is used for HTTPS. Usually port 443 is used

> ```
> SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:794:)
> ```

It is very likely that the server at port 80 did not reply with HTTPS but with some HTTP error because the message from the client was the start of a TLS handshake and not the expected HTTP request. But the client expected the reply to the TLS handshake and not a HTTP error. That's why you get this error.

> Without the proxy : fetch('https://example.com/rpc' ... the SSL request works fine.

That's because you use in this case `https://example.com` and not `https://example.com:80`. Because you don't give an explicit port it will use the default port for https, i.e. 443.

Comment: Yes, thnx. Still not working. I have updated my questtion.

Comment: @voscausa: the error message clearly says what the problem is: the certificate is for `*.appspot.com, ...` but you are accessing it with the name `localhost`. Since the name you use does not match the names in the certificate the certificate can not be validated.

Comment: OK. Thnx again. I found an option to change the origing and SOLVED. I have updated my Question with the option.

Answer (score 2):

While I am using the correct config with `changeOrigin: true` etc., but still meet 301 and option request, and can't reach the real backend server. Till I try to **clean the browser cache**, it works correctly.